# Gatling :Create a POST Request Dynamically using Session API programatically

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am load testing a API and I want to inject different data in different post Requests. I went through Session API of gatling and I am trying following code.But i keep on getting error 11:49:30.717

```
[gatling-1-16] ERROR io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction - 'create-profiles' failed to execute: No attribute named 'createProfile' is defined
```

Code for session:

```
  if (WRITES_PER_SECOND > 0) {
     scenarios.add( CoreDsl.scenario(CREATE_PROFILE)
              .feed(listFeeder(getFeed(noOfEntityIdsNeeded)).circular())
              .feed(listFeeder(TKN_FEED).circular())
              .exec(session -> {
                session.set("createProfile",*PayloadFeeder.getPayload()*);
                return session;
              })
              .exec(http("create-profiles").post(PROFILE_API_URL)
                      .header(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, MIME_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, TOKENIZED_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                      .header(X_APP_KEY_HEADER, X_APP_KEY_123_REG)
                      .header(IDEMPOTENCY_KEY_HEADER, ENTITY_ID_PLACEHOLDER)
                      .body(StringBody("${createProfile.jsonStringify()}")))
                      //.body(StringBody(session -> session.getString("postData"))))
              .injectClosed(
                      constantConcurrentUsers(WRITES_PER_SECOND).during(Duration.ofSeconds(duration)))
              .throttle(jumpToRps(WRITES_PER_SECOND), holdFor(Duration.ofSeconds(duration))));

    }


            session.set("createProfile",*PayloadFeeder.getPayload()*);
```

is where I call a function and get dynamic payload.
then I try to use this in below section,using session.get()

I also tried with session.set("postData,"jsonstringdynamic")
and session.getString("postData") but gatling does not find the value and injects NULL in http body.

Looking for some guidance on this

Answer (score 1):

```java
.exec(session -> {
  session.set("createProfile",*PayloadFeeder.getPayload()*);
  return session;
})
```

This is wrong. Please read the [Session API documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/#setting-attributes), Session instances are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I missed crucial info while reading docs. We have to return newSession since session API is immutable.
.exec(session -> {
Session newSession= session.set("postData",PayloadFeeder.getDynamicDataString());
return newSession;
})

that was it.

ModifiedCode

```
scenarios.add(CoreDsl.scenario(CREATE_PROFILE)
              .feed(listFeeder(getFeed(noOfEntityIdsNeeded)).circular())
              .feed(listFeeder(TKN_FEED).circular())
              .exec(session -> {
               Session newSession= session.set("postData",PayloadFeeder.getDynamicDataString());
                return newSession;
              })
              .exec(http("create-profiles").post(PROFILE_API_URL)
                      .header(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, MIME_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, TOKENIZED_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                      .header(X_APP_KEY_HEADER, X_APP_KEY_123_REG)
                      .header(IDEMPOTENCY_KEY_HEADER, ENTITY_ID_PLACEHOLDER)
                      .body(StringBody(session -> {
                              boolean contains=  session.contains("postData");
                              System.out.println("is property contains"+"["+contains+"]");
                              String data=session.getString("postData");
                              System.out.println("data is"+data);
                               return data ;
                              })))
              .injectClosed(
                      constantConcurrentUsers(WRITES_PER_SECOND).during(Duration.ofSeconds(duration)))
              .throttle(jumpToRps(WRITES_PER_SECOND), holdFor(Duration.ofSeconds(duration))));
```